# Matplot/Pandas X-axis is not showing for all the values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I ran this program. For some reason I am not getting all the X-axis values. Tried to change the data still no printing.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation 
from pandas import Timestamp
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as Tk
else:
    import tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()
top = Tk.Frame(root)
top.pack()
bottom = Tk.Frame(root)
bottom.pack()
fig = plt.Figure()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, top)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

canvas._tkcanvas.pack()

df = pd.read_csv("../data.csv") 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.suptitle('App Server CPU%', fontsize=12)

df['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
df = df.set_index('date')
grouped = df.groupby(['server'])
for key, group in grouped:
 group['utilization'].plot(label=key, ax=ax)

plt.legend(loc='best')

def on_closing():
 #if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
 root.destroy()
 root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
 root.lift()
 root.attributes('-topmost',True)
 root.mainloop()
```

```
date,server,utilization
2004-08-19,App1,105.01
2004-08-20,App1,106.06
2004-08-23,App1,116.3
2004-08-24,App1,116.8
2004-08-25,App1,110
2004-08-26,App1,110.2
2004-08-27,App1,113.51
2004-08-19,App2,126.01
2004-08-20,App2,127.27
2004-08-23,App2,139.56
2004-08-24,App2,140.16
2004-08-25,App2,132
2004-08-26,App2,132.24
2004-08-27,App2,136.21
2004-08-19,App3,157.52
2004-08-20,App3,159.09
2004-08-23,App3,174.45
2004-08-24,App3,175.2
2004-08-25,App3,165
2004-08-26,App3,165.3
2004-08-27,App3,170.26
```

Comment: Sorry for some reason I was not able to attach my data file in a proper format.

Comment: Your data ranges from the 19th of august to the 27th of august. This range is shown in the plot as well. So it is not obvious why you think that some x-axis values are missing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Only the date is showing in there not the month and year. For ex, In the first x-axis value Aug 19 2004, the rest are just only date

Comment: Yes that is desired. How would you like it to be instead? And what's more, in how far do other questions on that topic do not help?

Comment: Thanks I got it now. I was thinking all the x axis values with dd-Mon-yyyy. Let me set the data with mixed month to see. Again thanks for your input.

Comment: I was expecting similar to this https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrCVe.png

Comment: You would probably get that using compatibility mode, `df.plot(..., x_compat=True)`.